# How to detect that for current locale if MUI pack of Office is installed or not from C#

Tags: c#, ms-office, windows-mui

How to detect that for current locale if MUI pack of Office is installed or not from C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get what locale of Office is installed for example seeing the Registry entry...

for Office 2007

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Office\12.0\MsoExample\A\1030
```

the [LCID 1030](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx) tell you that the Danish (Denmark) MUI is installed.

if there is more, I can't assure you, I only have this installed, but you can make yourself that test.

Answer (score 0):

no you can't.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Office <- dosen't exist!
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0 <-- does exist, but dosen't contain any "A" keys anywhere, nor any MsoExample keys.